# Getting Jersey's JSON POJO support to work from embedded Jetty?

Tags: json, rest, jetty, jersey

I'm trying to get a simple object to JSON format from my Jetty server using Jersey.

I keep getting the error:

```
SEVERE: A message body writer for Java class my.package.resources.Album, and Java type class my.package.resources.Album, and MIME media type application/json was not found
```

One problem is that I'm not sure where to put the POJOMappingFeature with Jetty, I have tried the following but neither changes the error:

```
myServletHolder.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", "true");
```

and

```
myServletContextHandler.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", "true");
```

I know the basic REST functionality of Jersey is working because before I tried the JSON output I used plain text and it worked great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was super disappointed when I saw this one not answered as I've been fighting it all day.  Finally figured it out so here's what worked for me.

What I was doing:

```
    ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(new PackagesResourceConfig("my.package.with.resources")));
    servletHolder.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", "true");
```

What I needed to do:

```
    Map<String,Object> initMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    initMap.put("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", "true");
    initMap.put("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "my.package.with.resources");
    ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(new PackagesResourceConfig(initMap)));
```

I had to make sure to specify my Jersey packages and my POJOMappingFeature flag as init params.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you have `jackson` json-parser and `JAXB` lib in your classpath.

Comment: you must add more information for this to be complete